# VB.Net equivalent of "This" for Shared Methods

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

```
Public Class MyLongClassName

    Public Shared Name As String = "Ana"

    Public Shared Function GetName() As String
        Dim Name As String = "Beta"
        '... this is toooooo long
        Return MyLongClassName.Name
    End Function

    Public Shared Function GetName() As String
        Dim Name As String = "Beta"
        '... much better
        Return This.Name '<--- there is any keyword for this?
    End Function

End Class
```

I dont care only about long class names. Having a keyword to refer to the very class (like 'this' in static methods in Javascript) will be very useful along my journey.

Comment: Why do you need anything at all, what's wrong with just `Return Name`

Comment: For the case I have a variable also called 'Name' inside the method

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea anyway to have local variable and a field with the same name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To refer to a shared member within a shared method of the same class, you only have 2 choices:

1. Use the class name.
2. Use no qualifier and avoid locals with the same name.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent keyword is me. In place of This.

And this goes back to even VB days, and even VBA days

Thus

```
Return Me.Name
```

Edit:
As pointed out, me is not available in a shared class. So then just

```
Return Name
```

Will work fine, and so will

```
   Return MyLongClassName.Name
```

Comment: "Me" doesnt apply to Shared methods.

Comment: Ah, that does seem to be the case. Then a simple Return Name, or Return MyClassName.Name does work just fine. So, see my edit